# Blazor client side, server project not being published

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

When I publish my blazor client side app, it seems that server part of the app (hosted by asp.net core) is not published.

I figured out something is wrong when i could not access any of the api endpoints of the app.

What could I do to get all projects/assemblies published?

Comment: Can you tell us how you publish the stuff by updating your question with commands you do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a command line în your solution folder run `dotnet publish -c Release -o {pat to your output folder}`.
This will build and publish all your projects under the solution folder.

Comment: I was deploying it from client project instead from server project. That caused this issue.